# Form values via AJAX to PHP first being cut off and then not being recognized

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**Submitting the following form:**

```
<form name="register" method="post" onSubmit="registerUser();">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="user_name">Name</label>
            <input name="user_name" type="text" id="user_name" placeholder="Name" />
        <label for="user_email">Email</label>
            <input name="user_email" type="email" id="user_email" placeholder="Email"/>
        <label for="user_password">Password</label>
            <input name="user_password" type="password" id="user_password" placeholder="Password" />
        <input name="s" type="hidden" value="register" />
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

**via AJAX**

```
function registerUser(){
    var myform = $("form[name='register']"),
    data = {};
    myform.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();
        data[name] = value;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: urlService,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function(response){
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

The "s" value of "register was being cut off to "regist" when echoed in following PHP statement. So in an effort correct it I escaped the values as so in the prior jQuery statement:

```
value = escape(that.val());
```

This then allowed the full value to be passed, although adding "%20" to the name value. I continued as follows...

**forwarded on to PHP**

```
print_r($_POST);
try{
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    switch($_POST['s']){
        case 'register':
            $response = 'registered ok + ';
        break;
        case 'login':
        break;
    }
    $response = 'services read';
    echo $response;
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

At this point all of the $_POST values are being echoed, HOWEVER the value of "register" is not being recognized by the SWITCH statement.

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly nor at which point... any help in cleaning up these glitches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have a bug with your form: `onSubmit="return registerUser();">`

Comment: Why are you reinventing jQuery's [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)?

Comment: Thanks epascarello for the point. Checking out the serialize method right now.

Comment: @epascarello Used the serialize method, received the URL string, passed via AJAX using the GET type, variables are intact but the SWITCH statement is still ignoring the "s" value of "register.

Comment: Disregard... basic miscoding. Wasn't testing properly.

Comment: You also added the missing `return`?

Comment: @epascarello Added it. Thanks!

Also, if you write out your two recommendations (return & serialize) I'll mark is as the answer. I'm still not sure why POSTing the variables didn't work however.